# This regex seems to be not working in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match for a user password combination and I have tried the following.

```
combination='User'+' '+'Password'
import re
print(combination)
with open("file.txt",'rb') as file:
    if re.search('^{0}$'.format(re.escape(combination)), file.read(), flags=re.M):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print "no"
```

My file.txt contents:

```
User Password
Sam  Somepass
Ron  Ssss
```

Still when I run this code I get the message `"no"`. I'm not able to figure out why.

Edit:
There is **exactly one space** between the `Name` and the `Password.`

My goal is to search for the exact string `User Password` which I receive from another file.

Comment: Add more content of your file..

Comment: Hi, Actually there is more content in the file. There are 5 lines to be exact, with the user and password separated by spaces

Comment: Are they separated by an *arbitrary number* of spaces?

Comment: Then please post all the unneeded text in that file where as we understand what `regex `to use to extract needed text from the unneeded- i mean just exact dummy of that file.

Comment: btw, I am getting correct o/p. `sh-4.3$ python main.py
User Password yes sh-4.3$

Comment: Oh, you’re using `rb` as a mode, too; how about just `r`?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I thought it's a safe practice to read any file in binary mode. Will this create issues for a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good. Just check that there is no space before and after `User Password`.

Otherwise, you can use this regex with `\s*` to match any space, tab or newline character.

E.g :

```python
import re
user = 'Sam'
password = 'Somepass'
with open("test.txt",'r') as file:
    if re.search('\s*{0}\s+{1}\s*'.format(user, password), file.read(), flags=re.M):
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
```

Check it live : [here](https://regex101.com/r/fU2pQ6/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess that was the issue.

Comment: why not: '.*{0}.*'. this code works only for 1 pair.

Comment: it works too, yeah but why match any single character whereas there are only space?

Comment: not working: https://ideone.com/8z6ad5 . you regex is: begin of line->any spaces->User Password->any space->end of line. but file contains many pair. file.read() return  full content like:"User1 Pass1\nUser2 Pass2\n etc"

Comment: oh,  I understand. That is because @soma didn't express that it would like to search a user and its password when he posted his question. I thought that he wanted to just test if the beginning of the file. I have updated my answer with a correct example to search user and password.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
combination='User Password'
with open("file.txt",'rb') as file:
    if re.search('.*{0}.*'.format(combination), file.read(), flags=re.M):
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
```

Comment: I assume OP was using the "combination" variable because his intent is to ultimately accept user and password as inputs. That would be why he used the string.format() function, and it would make manually typing out the regex like this impractical.

Comment: If I want to pass the combination from a variable how do I edit this code? Like I don't want to hardcode the value "User Password"

Answer (score 0):

I just ran that code, and here were the problems with it.

1. Assuming you are running python 3 you need parenthesis around "no".
2. Other than that the "b" flag you use to open the file sets it into binary mode.  In python 3 I get the error "TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object"  I would suggest removing it since you are operating on a text file.

The following code worked for me in python 3.3.4

```
combination='User'+' '+'Password'
import re
print(combination)
with open("file.txt",'r') as file:
    if re.search('^{0}$'.format(re.escape(combination)), file.read(),flags=re.M):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print("no")
```